# What are most important recommendations for choosing clothing for my dog?

Tags: dogs, health, safety

What are most important recommendations for choosing clothing for my dog? What pets costumes store would you recommend?

Comment: It *really* feels like the question itself is just spambait, especially with the really close, and unimaginative user names.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty: don't put clothes on your dog.

If you simply have to, or you have a dog that likes wearing jackets or something, I'd suggest buying them at your local walmart/target or something along that lines.

But if it's a novelty costume, there are many trustworthy websites that you can find by simply looking up 'Dog T-Rex Costume' for example.

Answer (score 0):

So, this can become a strong debate, and seems a little opinion based but I'll thrown in what "my answer" would be anyways. I had a pretty strong opinion for years that putting clothes on dogs is against nature, but so are A LOT of things that caring pet people do for their pets, so if it feels right to you, and doesn't harm your pet, go for it!

When I worked in a pet store, I heard some of the craziest reasons for wanting and needing pet clothing. Based on these stories, I'd put pet clothes into two categories necessity and accessory.

Necessary clothing would be:

- Stress - "Thundershirts" and "Comfortcoats" are made to swaddle and fit tightly on pressure points to relieve separation and thunder anxiety.
- Warmth - coats and sweaters that are purchased for hairless pets that get cold, sick pets with poor circulation or senior pets that also have issues keeping warm.
- Potty problems - ponchos and raincoats, rainboots- although rare, I heard a story from a lady who has to put a raincoat on her dog because he refused to use the potty outside if he was getting wet. I hear A LOT that not all dogs will do their business when raining because they don't like their feet to get wet, but I've personally not experienced that as an issue.

Accessory clothing would be:

- Dresses, pants, bows, hats, etc.

For putting clothes on your pet:

- as a Fashion accessory or to match it's owners clothing;
- for holiday events and parties;
- or simply because you think it's cute!

I would just consider the thought "is this harmful?" Does is have drawstrings, buttons, tassles, bows etc that could be a choke hazard? Does the clothing cause my pup discomfort? Am I overheating my pet during warm weather? Can he or she still eliminate when wearing this, or will my pet hold it in? Does my pet have any sores, abscesses or rashes where the clothes could irritate it further?

Chances are if you're "pro-clothes" your opinion on the matter won't change because you read this, but maybe this will help someone!